# I have a problem with "snapshot.data.docs.length" on flutter 2.5

Tags: database, flutter, dart

I following step by step the tutorial on this video

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gdghvuFDinc&list=PLtIU0BH0pkKrQZUFWENF_VXINhfv9WiIA&index=12

But I can't use "docs" in "snapshot.data.docs.length" that I don't know how to fix, this is my code

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:my_project/common.dart';
import 'package:my_project/screen/apps/todo/components/addTodoTasks.dart';
import 'package:my_project/screen/apps/todo/components/todoCards.dart';

class todoHome extends StatefulWidget {
  const todoHome({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _todoHomeState createState() => _todoHomeState();
}

class _todoHomeState extends State<todoHome> {
  final Stream<QuerySnapshot> _stream =
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("todo").snapshots();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        elevation: 0,
        title: Text(
          "Today's Schedule",
          style: TextStyle(
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 37, color: Colors.black),
        ),
        actions: [
          CircleAvatar(
            backgroundImage: AssetImage("assets/image/Minh1Punch.jpg"),
          ),
          rs(20)
        ],
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        items: [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.home,
                size: 35,
                color: Colors.black,
              ),
              title: Container()),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: InkWell(
                onTap: () {
                  Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (builder) => addTodoPage()),
                      (route) => false);
                },
                child: Container(
                  height: 52,
                  width: 52,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      shape: BoxShape.circle,
                      gradient: LinearGradient(colors: [
                        Colors.blue.shade300,
                        Colors.purple.shade500
                      ])),
                  child: Icon(
                    Icons.add,
                    size: 37,
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              title: Container()),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.settings,
                size: 35,
                color: Colors.black,
              ),
              title: Container())
        ],
      ),
      body: StreamBuilder(
        stream: _stream,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if(!snapshot.hasData) {
            return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          }
          return ListView.builder(
            itemCount: snapshot.data.docs.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index){

            return TodoCard(
              title: "Hi",
              iconData: Icons.add_a_photo,
              iconColor: Colors.black26,
              cardColor: Colors.purple.shade300);
          });
        }
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I'm new, can anyone help me. Sorry if my grammar quite bad

Thank you so much!!

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: I think you have to add the bang operator : itemCount: snapshot.data!.docs.length,

Comment: @Diwyansh I just follow the clip and I cannot use "docs" in snapshot.data

Comment: @mariofrancois I tried it but it did not work

Comment: @pckien there should be an error in your console just copy and paste it here

Comment: @Diwyansh oh it's "The getter 'docs' isn't defined for the type 'Object'.\nTry importing the library that defines 'docs', correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'docs'."